# VScode Error while Deployeing LWC component (reading 'split') undefinrd

Tags: lightning-web-components, deployment, vs-code

[image]I am getting error while I am deploying the LWC component
ERROR running force:source:push:  Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')I don't use any split property in my code, I also try to deploy another component but it giving me the same error.

Comment: I am seeing this message with various different metadata items. I see this with scratch orgs, and it seems to be some issue with the org or perhaps the tracking state. My solution has been to abandon the scratch org and create a new one.

Comment: Yes, after deleting the scratch org, it works fine - thanks @PhilW